# How do I change the refresh my xcode workflow to match my new project name

Tags: xcode, github, xcode-cloud

I have recently done a rename of my entire project from Pantry to PantryPal. Everything has worked except the workflow in xcode cloud that runs when I commit to any of my branches. It let me change the project file name but not the scheme name which is weird. Any ideas?

I tried creating a new workflow but it still thinks that the scheme name is Pantry and not PantryPal despite being pretty sure that I updated it correctly.

[screenshot of workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0u4T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Strange. It just refreshed after about 30 minutes or so and let me click PantryPal.